# Position widget relative to another in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a design that I think is fairly simple, have an image centered on screen, and 30 points below it have some text.

I know I can probably do it by manually by running my own computations and using Stack layout, but can I just somehow use `center` for the image, and then place the `Text` relative to it?

Thx.

[image]

Comment: use `CustomMultiChildLayout` then - with `Stack` it would not be that easy as you dont know the size of your image, or you know?

Comment: if you don't know the size of your image, it should be fairly hard to do that. with CustomMultiChildLayout, how can you do that? @pskink

Comment: @JoeHu simply call `layoutChild` and `positionChild` methods for each child: the first method returns a size so you can use it for precise position

Comment: Thx, I was hoping for something simple...

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor:  Color.fromRGBO(187, 41, 42, 1),

  body: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(


          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: stackHeight * 0.4,
              ),
              Container(
                  width: stackWidth * 0.75,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/lo1.png')),


              SizedBox(
                height: stackHeight * 0.3,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                height: stackHeight * 0.04,
                child: Text(
                  'Powered By',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.5),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: stackHeight * 0.040,
                child: Image.asset('assets/brand.png'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
     ),
    );
   }
```

***Result***
[image]

Comment: Not sure I follow this answer...